# Damage in Vagrant Story

Tags: vagrant-story

In Square Enix's Vagrant Story there is a massive engine for crafting your own weapons out of components of current weapons, merging weapons, adding gems, etc etc.

I never actually made use of this as it was too confusing and I figured that the game would supply me with *decent enough* equipment to get through the game.

After the first 3-4 hours of the game (where I deal an average of 50 damage) I find that all my equipment does 1 damage. The only way I've been able to make my way through the game (particularly boss fights) is to use two chains that will slowly develop the damage. This eventually got too frustrating because if I missed a chain, the boss would turn around and kill me in one strike.

I started another game and actually tried to make use of the blacksmithy engine, but with no luck..

Am I missing something obvious or are your weapons meant to be this feeble beyond the first 10% of the game?

Comment: Isn't it a PS1 game?  Or was it rereleased for the PS2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crafting and damage systems are extraordinarily complex in Vagrant Story.  It doesn't surprise me that if you didn't craft new weapons frequently you'd have a tough time doing damage.  Even if you are, but you're not doing all you can to have optimal gear, it's still very tough.

The "Risk" concept in Vagrant Story is a bit weird too.  The more you combo, the higher your risk goes - and this means that you'll hit harder but miss more often and be at greater risk for taking damage.  I remember some of the last bosses in the game I had to max out my risk completely and do 99-long chains in order to do hardly any damage, and I was crafting and improving my gear frequently.

If you're keen on taking this challenging game on, I'd suggest following a guide and using some extreme patience :)

Answer (score 1):

the whole crafting is there to give you the ultimate material in both weapon and armour to defeat the last boss with ease beside it with crafting you can get the ultimate  type of both weapon and armour available in this game. if you have no idea about materials I have to say there are different type of materials that weapons and armours can be found during the game. the first is Leather represented with "L", Wood with "W", Bronze with "B", Iron with "I", Hagane with "H", Silver with "S" and finally Damascus with "D". you can find better performance from two same weapon with different material, for example: D>S>H>I>B>W

that was about material, now about the quality of the tool itself.
we have many weapon and armour class in this lovely game. for example dagger, if you combine two daggers together you have a chance to upgrade your dagger, yes of course it's not based on random, it will follow a very beautiful rule. but you have no idea about bunch of names if I write them here. you should finish the game or at least proceed till last boss, then you should go to farm and upgrade your weapons and armours.

the most important thing in this game is the elemental rules. you should get to know about what boss you are fighting, with what element that boss damage, and what element is  it's weakness, then pick the right armour to avoid boss damage and the right weapon to defeat that boss. this rule is about all Units that are in this beautiful game include bosses.